# DisMiss the Navigation bar image

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview, uinavigationbar

I want to dismiss my navigation bar image(*not the background image*).That is i have set navigation bar image on the left side . when i go to the next controller the image overlaps the back button . This is my home screen with image in blue marked . [image: Home Screen]

And this my second screen With image overlaped

[image]

And this the code i used to set the image in the bar

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
UIImageView *barImg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 3, 49, 39)];
barImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"smalllogo.png"];

[bar addSubview:barImg];
[barImg release];
```

Now i dont want the image in my other screens what can i do for that?

Comment: second screen you need image disappear?

Comment: yes. I dont want that in my 2nd screen

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is Add your image in side the `viewWillAppear:` method and remove it from the navigation bar when `viewWillDisappear:` method. Related code block as follows.

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
    UIImageView *barImg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 3, 49, 39)];
    barImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"smalllogo.png"];
    barImg.tag = 100;
    [bar addSubview:barImg];
    [barImg release];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
    [[bar viewWithTag:100] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Or Here's another simple solution. Add below code segment to `viewWillAppear:` method

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smalllogo.png"]]];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:item];
[item release];
```

Comment: I have updated the answer with another solution. if you think this is correct answer. Please accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have added the image in the navigation bar but not removed it before moving into other view.
Use `

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [barImg removeFromSuperview];
}`
```

to remove it from superview.